# Trouble with data validation in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

So I'm trying to save data with 0 minimum value and 200 maximum value
If I type in the number between in the appropriate range it works fine
But if I try to type in different number (-1 or 203 for example) it gets stuck on this value. The alert controller is presented but when I try to type in the legal value it shows in console the previous value (-1 or 203) and the last value changes only if I type in another bad number (like 509 and alert controller is presented also).
I get errors 1610 and 1620, but I don't understand how to fix this. I need to make sure that if the user types in the wrong value and then the good one everything works fine and it it saves the data.

Here is my code for saving

chislo = UITextField

```
@IBAction func saveNote(_ sender: Any) {


    if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.coreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext {

        let note = BreathingNote(context: context)

        chislo.keyboardType = .numberPad

        note.chdd = NSNumber(value: Int16(chislo.text!)!)  
        note.date = dateLabel!.text
        note.time = timeLabel!.text
        if noteAboutDrug?.text != nil {
            note.sideNote = noteAboutDrug.text
        }
        note.fullDate = (dateLabel.text! + timeLabel.text!)

        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Saving done!")
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Type in two-figure number", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Хорошо", style: .cancel)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            present(alertController, animated: true)
            print(error, error.localizedDescription, error.userInfo)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Validating the data when you try to save it is too late. Validate the data when the user first entered it, or at least before you try to save it.  You haven’t shown any code where you collect the updated number from the user and updated your managed object

Comment: I use validation in xcdatamodeld in Data Model Inspector, so it is supposed to check value when the data is trying to be saved. It is supposed to rise an error in this case

Comment: And it is raising an error, but consider your user experience.  It is nicer to validate as you go rather than presenting them with a modal pop up when they try to save.  Regardless, you have shown code for the alert controller, but this is working.  You haven't shown the code where you update the managed object with the new data that the user has entered, which is the code that isn't working; show that

Comment: Ok, I replace some words for better understanding;
entity.attribute = NSNumber(value: Int16(textField.text!)!)

Comment: You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46595153/edit) your question to show more code in context.  My suspicion is that you are creating a new `NSManagedObject` and saving that with the updated data, but the previous managed object is also still there, so when you save the managed object context you are still getting an error on the initial object

Comment: Edited; and I suppose you are right but I still don't know how to fix this

Comment: See that line `let note = BreathingNote(context: context)`; that creates a new managed object, but the old one with the error is still there in the context.  Call `context.delete(note)` immediately after you get the saving error to remove the object with the bad data from the context.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `saveNote` function you are allocating a new `BreathingNote` with `let note = BreathingNote(context: context)`.  You then set the values on this object and try and save it.  If the save fails you prompt the user to correct their data and eventually call `saveNote` again, where you create a new `BreathingNote` object with the updated data.

The *original* `BreathingNote` is still there in the managed object context, however, When you call `save`, Core Data attempts to save the original note and the new one; Since the original note still has the bad data, the save fails again.  You can remove the note with the bad data by calling

```
context.delete(note)
```

when you catch the failed save; this will remove the object with the invalid data from the context